# What speed-up do you get with 10 versus 40 processors?

Tags: parallel-processing, multiprocessing, parallelism-amdahl

Suppose you want to perform two sums: one is a sum of 10 scalar variables, and
one is a matrix sum of a pair of two-dimensional arrays, with dimensions 10 by 10.
For now let’s assume only the matrix sum is parallelizable; What speed-up do you get with 10 versus 40 processors?

**My Understanding:**

10x10 matrix + 10 scalar variables = 110t

With 10 processors, (100/10)t + 10t = 20t

Speed-up=110/20=5.5;

With 40 processors, (100/40)t + 10t = 12.5t

Speed-up=110/12.5=8.8;

It is given in the solution book that  we get about **55%** of the potential speed-up with 10 processors, but only **22%** with 40.

I understand the 55% but how does that 22% come?

Comment: `5.5/10==0.55` and `8.8/40==0.22` ?  Surely ?

Comment: **Nota Bene:** What is your formal definition of a term "speed-up"? Is it the very same, as Alan Karp has used in February 1986 ( then IBM Palo Alto Scientific Center, later HP ) in his Letter to the Editor, CACM Forum, offering a prize money for any +200x speedup on his defined problem classes, or some other? ( Never hunt figures to match without being safe first on the meaning of each and every term ... be it in a Lecturer's book or anywhere else ... hunting vapourised shadows in the morning Sun is way easier task ... )